# Trying to unbox an object to IEnumerable, get IEnumerable is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' error

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

I want to unbox an object into an IEnumerable. I check that if the object can be assigned an IEnumerable and then if so I want to loop through the values in the object. However, when I do the following:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<IRecord>).IsAssignableFrom(propertyValue.GetType()))
{
    foreach (var property in IEnumerable<IRecord>(propertyValue))
    {
        var test = property;
    }
}
```

the IEnumerable gives the following error:

```
Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<test.Database.IRecord>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'   D:\test.Test\ElectronicSignatureRepositoryTest.cs   397 46  test.Test
```

How can I assign propertyValue to be an IEnumerable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<IRecord>).IsAssignableFrom(propertyValue.GetType()))
{
    foreach (var property in (IEnumerable<IRecord>)propertyValue)
    {
        var test = property;
    }
}
```

You can also do:

```
var enumerable = propertyValue as IEnumerable<IRecord>;
if (enumerable != null)
{
    foreach (var property in enumerable)
    {
        var test = property;
    }
}
```

Comment: The latter is generally preferred to reflection. (@Niek, not @mdm.)